# Adjust binwidth size for faceted dotplot with free y axis

Tags: ggplot2, facet-wrap

I would like to adjust the `binwidth` of a faceted `geom_dotplot` while keeping the dot sizes the same.

Using the default `binwidth` (1/30 of the data range), I get the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(
  t = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  x = 1, 
  y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center") +
  facet_wrap(~t, scales="free_y")
```

[image]

However, if I change the `binwidth` value, the new value is taken as an absolute value (and not the ratio of the data range), so the two facets get differently sized dots:

```
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", binwidth=2) +
```

[image]

Is there a way to adjust `binwidth` so it is relative to its facet's data range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be via multiple `geom_dotplot`s which allows to set the binwidth for each facet separately. This however requires some manual work to compute the `binwidth`s so that the dots are the same size for each facet:

```r
library(ggplot2)

y_ranges <- tapply(df$y, factor(df$t), function(x) diff(range(x)))
binwidth1 <- 2

scale2 <- binwidth1 / (y_ranges[[1]] / 30)
binwidth2 <-  scale2 * y_ranges[[2]] / 30

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_dotplot(data = ~subset(.x, t == 1), binaxis="y", stackdir="center", binwidth = binwidth1) +
  geom_dotplot(data = ~subset(.x, t == 2), binaxis="y", stackdir="center", binwidth = binwidth2) +
  facet_wrap(~t, scales="free_y")
```

[image]